# How to Load Image from a URL which generates random captcha image. Here the url does not refer to a specific image but a dynamically generated image

Tags: java, android, image

How to load an image from a URL which generates a random captcha image. Here the URL does not refer to a specific image file but a dynamically generated and named image file. For example, http://example.com/my_image.png refers to `my_image.png` file. But in my case the URL generates an image of captcha code. This is my URL:

> https://www.msrtc.gov.in/captcha.php?381022315

I have tried all the other solutions, e.g. Picasso, setting this URL in WebView and I have also tried following code:

```
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVcaptcha))
            .execute("https://www.msrtc.gov.in/captcha.php?381022315");

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
{
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage)
    {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try
        {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result)
        {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
```

None of these solutions are working. Please help me through this.

Comment: So you're trying to avoid a CAPTCHA?

Comment: No, I am not trying to avoid a CAPTCHA. I want to display it in my app. But I am unable to do that since the URL mentioned above dynamically generates an image. If you click on the URL, you will see that everytime a different image is generated. If it were a static image, I could have easily displayed it. Please help.

Comment: @AbhijeetKharatmol Have you found any solution for this?